# How to replace a Word in DF Column with another Word using Python -without including the substring

Tags: python, sas, code-conversion

I am trying to achieve the functionality of **SAS TRANWRD**  Function in Python to replace a **'WORD'** with another **'WORD'.**

I have tried using **str.replace** and **replace** method available in Python but these methods are *also replacing the SUBSTRING* in addition to replacing the word.

Code:

```
DICT1 = {'NZ':'NEW ZEALAND'}

for k,v in DICT1.items():
    df['COL1'] = df['COL1'].str.replace(k,v)
```

e.g.:

```
NZ COMPANY LIMITED --> NEW ZEALAND COMPANY LIMITED - *(Expected)*

GONZU ENTERPRISE --> GONEW ZEALANDU ENTERPRISE - *(Unexpected)*
```

In SAS this issue is taken care because TRANWRD Function only replaces the word after finding the space boundaries.

Can someone help how to achieve the similar functionality in Python ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression search pattern that utilizes the word boundary metacharacter `\b`

Example:

```
import re

seekword = "Bob"
rplcword = "Bubba"

phrase = "Hello there Bob"
phrasex = re.sub(r"\b"+seekword+r"\b", rplcword, phrase)

print (phrasex)
```

Example 2:

Loop over multiple phrases and replacements

```
import re

PHRASES = \
[ 'Bill is from AU' \
, 'Bob is from NZ' \
, 'Bobby visited NZA' \
]

WORDMAPS = \
{ 'Bob': 'Bubba' \
, 'NZ': 'NEW ZEALAND'
}

for index, phrase in enumerate(PHRASES):
    
    phrasex = phrase
    
    for k,v in WORDMAPS.items():
        phrasex = re.sub(r"\b"+k+r"\b", v, phrasex)
        
    PHRASES[index] = phrasex
        
print (PHRASES)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Is there a way to implement your suggestion using Python Dictionary ? I have a long list of the 'seekword' and its corresponding 'rplcword'